# Failed to run constructor: TypeError: Result of expression 'cordova.addPlugin' [undefined] is not a function

Tags: jquery, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I would try to make one code in phonegap there was occur one problem please help to solve this error.

Failed to run constructor: TypeError: Result of expression 'cordova.addPlugin' [undefined] is not a function.

Answer (score 2):

That error simply means that 'cordova' was never initialized. That could be because of one of the following possibilities:

1. You didn't include some version of `cordova-X.X.X.js` in your `index.html` file.
2. You have the `cordova-X.X.X.js` script referenced in your `index.html`, but the `cordova-X.X.X.js` doesn't exist in the path that you provided.
3. You are developing on iOS and you're trying to use the `cordova-X.X.X.js` that was made for Android (substitute any platforms there... the point is you have to use the `cordova-X.X.X.js` that was made for the platform for which you are developing).

If you're using Cordova 2.3.0, all the references to `cordova-X.X.X.js` above will be `cordova-2.3.0.js`.

Here is the full documentation to Cordova 2.3.0: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/index.html

Here are various getting started guides, one for each of the platforms that Cordova supports: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/guide_getting-started_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20Guides

If this answer didn't solve your problem, you need to edit your question and fill in some missing information: Platform, Cordova version, code samples.